# Gradient and Image on Form Submit button?

Tags: html, css

I was wondering if there is a way to have an image on a submit button while preserving the gradient.

Heres the gradient I have and am using.

[image]

But I want to add an image as well, like below. But by adding the image it overrides the gradient.

[image]

Heres the code I use to add the button.

```
background-position:  center left;
background-image: url(../images/icons/cross.png);
background-repeat: no-repeat;
```

Below is photoshoped version of what I want, as you can see both gradient and image are present.

[image]

Any ideas? Obviously you can't add an image to a submit button via html? Or can you?

**Update**

Heres the snippets of the code

Gradient CSS

```
.whitegrad
{
background:#fefefe;
background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  #fefefe 0%, #e3e3e3 100%);
background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(50%,#fefefe), color-stop(100%,#e3e3e3));
   /* etc etc */
}
```

HTML for the form

```
<form action='' method='post' class='addtofavorites' >
    <input type='hidden' class='atf_video_id' name='atf_video_id' value='' />
    <input class='whitebtn whitegrad rndrgt' type='submit' value='Add to Favorites' />

</form>
```

Comment: Could you show the actual HTML for the button? How is the gradient currently being applied to the button?

Comment: Using the `background` property. Like `background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #83ab53 0%,#7ca44b 49%,#739946 50%,#6b903e 100%);` Obviously, theres one for each browser.

Comment: Please add the exact CSS you are using to your post. Having the actual code is essential when debugging things.

Comment: Hmm its not really a bug. Because I know whats happening. The image is overriding the gradient. Im looking for ways of adding an image to the submit button whilst preserving a gradient.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why would you use the image of a cross, when you have an actual text version of that available to you?

You could either include the '+' within the button text:

```
<button type="submit">+ Add to Favourites</button>
```

Or use CSS-generated content to add it:

```
<button type="submit">Add to Favourites</button>

button:before {
    content: '+ ';
}
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/2kP6b/1/).

Comment: ..and the winner is... David Thomas, for his lateral thinking skills!

Answer (score 1):

The `<button>` tag lets you put HTML inside of it.  You can add `onclick` + `onkeypress` event handlers to call `submit()` on the form.  Then, you can keep the background gradient on the `<button>`.

You can also use multiple backgrounds with CSS3, but it isn't well-supported yet.

Answer (score 1):

#### HTML

You can’t add an image to `<input type="submit">` via HTML, although the `<button>` element can contain arbitrary HTML. [This article](http://particletree.com/features/rediscovering-the-button-element/) is worth a look, although I think there are some issues in getting the `<button>` to submit the form it’s inside reliably in different browsers.

#### CSS

To do it just with CSS, you need to use [multiple background images](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-background/#background-image). Browser support for them is:

- Chrome 1+
- Firefox 3.6+
- IE 9+
- Opera 10.5+
- Safari 2+

It’s a bit tricky combining that with CSS gradients, as Firefox, Opera and Chrome/Safari have their own gradient syntaxes, but here’s an example for Firefox:

```
background-image: url(http://yubelr.com/images/icons/cross.png), -moz-linear-gradient(top, #fdd, #966);
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-position: 3px 50%, 0 0;
padding-left: 10px;
```

- http://jsfiddle.net/CjDZr/1/

You’d need another `background-image` statement for each different browser gradient syntax.

CSS3 is fun!

Comment: This is a good ideas, but as is the problem the web design, browser compatibly.

Comment: Sure — if you’re not happy with a different experience on older browsers, this isn’t the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

The button element lets you add HTML inside, as stated by John Kurlak and Paul D. Waite. Thus it's compatible with IE8- in your case: you can have a gradient on the button and an HTML image or a background-image with an additional `span`.

HTML image: **http://jsfiddle.net/fm2s5/1/**

background-image and span: **http://jsfiddle.net/VYwhD/**

First thing to fix with form elements is font-size and font-family, then line-height and then play with padding in order to get the desired height (though don't fix the height, text could expand when zooming if users wish so and it's unnecessary. Padding is enough).
Vertical-align is a bit tricky, it'll be different with and without an HTML image but if you choose one of the two method, there won't be discrepancies.

I used http://fvsch.com/code/button-css/ for button reset and http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/#fefefe+0,e3e3e3+100;Custom for gradient including IE.